# Почему в C++ нельзя больше одной реализации int main(){}?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Почему в C++ нельзя больше одной реализации `int main(){}`? Выдаёт ошибку, спасибо заранее.

Comment: А скажите, какую из реализаций нужно выполнять при запуске программы? Если у вас их несколько?

Comment: Вторую..........

Comment: Почему вторую? Но если вторую - то зачем тогда первая?

Comment: Ни в С, ни в С++ не разрешаются множественные определения одной и той же функции. `main` тут ничем не выделяется среди остальных функций. Откуда вдруг даже возник такой вопрос?

Answer (score 3):

В C++ функция `main` определяет точку входа программы (т. е. ее начало) и такая функция может быть единственной. Если Вам нужно две функции `main`, можете попробовать объявить одну из них в другом пространстве имён:

```
// Функция main в пространстве имён example
namespace example {
  int main() { return 0; } 
}

// Глобальная функция main, в которой можно вызвать функцию main из пространства имён example

int main() { example::main(); }
```

Comment: поле переменных?

Comment: namespace - пространство имен

Comment: @Croessmah, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

В Linux gcc/g++ это сделать можно (подозреваю, что в винде (и даже в visual-c++) [тоже](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2290587/7286264)).

Для того, чтобы внешний символ (например имя функции, в т.ч. `main`) можно было определить более одного раза его надо сделать с атрибутом **weak** для линкера.

Вот пример:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat tt1.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int ac, char *av[])  __attribute__ ((weak));

int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  puts("tt1 main");
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat tt2.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int ac, char *av[])  __attribute__ ((weak));

int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  puts("tt2 main");
}

avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc tt1.c tt2.c && ./a.out
tt1 main
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc tt2.c tt1.c && ./a.out
tt2 main
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ tt2.c tt1.c && ./a.out
tt2 main
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ tt1.c tt2.c && ./a.out
tt1 main
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Если в одном (но только одном!) файле определить main без weak, например:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat tt3.c
#include <stdio.h>


int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  puts("strong main");
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ tt1.c tt2.c tt3.c && ./a.out
strong main
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

то будет вызвана именно эта функция